# Are there multiple "special values" for large object descriptors

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I'm dealing with this error message from postgresql:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid large-object descriptor: 1
```

This has been thrown a couple of times from a Spring application, where the `Blob` is acquired from a database entity object that, in turn, has been acquired by invoking a method annotated `@Transactional`.

Googling the error message led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445713/postgres-and-large-objects-invalid-large-object-descriptor-0#), where the invalid descriptor's value is `0`. A [page from postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/lo-interfaces.html) suggests to me that a large object descriptor is simply an integer with an arbitrary value (something like a DB id?).

So, is there a difference in meaning between the two values, or is this a slight difference in how implementations indicate a closed blob?

Comment: You shouldn't be using large objects to begin with, but `bytea`

Comment: The error message means that there is no large object with that OID. Probably some buggy code stored a value in that column that was taken from thin air.